# Creating a matrix with the filtered image of webcam?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix

I have a problem with my graduation project. I am a new user this site. I am sorry if i will do a fault.
Now my problem, I am taking frames with my webcam in python/openCV and filtering it with red and blue threshold. I could this part. But i wanna create a matrix with thresholded image. Is it possible?

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

# Take each frame
_, frame = cap.read()

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

lower_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255]) 
red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) # I have the Red threshold image.

# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
mask = blue_mask + red_mask

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break
```

This is the code of threshold filter. What will i do next part for matrix? [This is my threshold filter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ5lL.jpg) Please do not see outside of my platform :)

I wanna write the red is '1' in matrix and the others are '0', the last thing blue is '2' or 'X'.

Comment: You could try to use mask[mask == 255]= X

Comment: Thx for comment but i could not understand u very well. I have a matrix all elements of it are 0. If I could write the code which is put 1 when it sees red and put X when it sees blue. Could u do me a favor with that?

Comment: InRange does the thresholding for you. So what you get is a matrix with 255 for all red or blue pixel otherwise 0. so you need to set every non zero Pixel in your blue mask to X and all non zero pixel in your red mask to 1

Comment: Thanks friend. I have a last question: Am i must divide my image to grids for convert to matrix or it is not necessary? I am not good with python, pls tell it to me like i am an idiot :)

Comment: The data structure is a multidimensional array. So you already have what you wanted. Read [here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) for a detailed explanation. What di you want to do with the "matrix" after the processing?

Comment: It is my graduation project. After converting the image to matrix, we will solve maze, we wanna reach the ball to a finish point. Thanks for reply, i will look ur link. If i have a question could i ask u?

Comment: You should ask your question here in the forum so everybody can help you.

Comment: Hello again, i did a matrix which is 24x24 and full of zero but i can not achieve convert my image to this matrix. Because of that i can not fill th matrix about red and blue mask. Please help me.

Comment: Is your image 24x24 pixels too? You have to explain your problem more detailed

Comment: My image 480x480 pixels, i wanna divide it to 24x24 squares and these squares are elements of my matrix. If a square has a red pixel, i write a "1" to matrix element which is reference of the square.